# Copy just the 64 byte partition table using dd

Tags: unix, partitioning, mbr, dd, boot-partition

Given:

```
===MBR INFO===
MBR SECTOR NAME             BYTES
code area                   440(max. 446)
disk signature (optional)   4
Usually nulls; 0x0000       2
Table of primary partitions 64(Four 16-byte entries, IBM partition table scheme)
MBR signature;0xAA55        2

MBR, total size: 446 + 64 + 2 = 512
```

I believe the [dd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd) command to copy **JUST** 64 byte partition table would be:

```
dd obs=2 seek=223 count=32 if=/path/to/some_mbr.bin of=/dev/sda
```

Is this correct,

and/or is there a better way?

Comment: There might be a slight confusion with the question - you don't exclusively state, whether you want to make a backup of the **MBR** or actually restore it. Supposedly the latter, as you are using **seek** and a .bin file for **if**

Answer (score 2):

If some_mbr.bin is a full mbr, you need to skip the code in the input file too.

```
dd bs=1 if=/path/to/some_mbr.bin of=/dev/sda skip=446 seek=446 count=64
```

Of course you could do that also with `vi -b /path/to/some_mbr.bin /dev/sda` with yank and put (if you dare).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it? I just did and the output file was 16KB, not 64 bytes (try looking at the man page you linked to and the values of obs and ibs).

Try setting the blocksize (both for read and write) to 2, and skip reading the input you don't want rather than reading it all and only writing what you want.

So you'd end up with something along the lines of:

> dd bs=2 skip=223 count=32 if=/path/to/some_mbr.bin of=/dev/sda

It would also be easier to read if you had a blocksize of 1 rather than 2 and mean no more doubling and halving numbers in your head.

I'd try reading the mbr and writing it to a file and checking with a hex viewer before I was brave enough to write to the mbr though.